# How to map View Model Object to Entity Object using Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

How to map the view model to the entity for this type of object?
I have an Entity **Word** like

```
public class Word: BaseEntity<long>
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Definition { get; set; }
    
    public List<WordQuest>? WordQuestList { get; set; }
}

public class WordQuest
{
    public long WordId { get; set; }
    public Word? Word { get; set; }

    public long WordOptionId { get; set; }
    public WordOption? WordOption { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class WordOption : BaseEntity<long>
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public List<WordQuest>? WordList { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class WordVm
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Definition { get; set; }

    public List<WordQuestVm>? WordQuestList { get; set; }

    public WordVm()
    {
        WordQuestList = new List<WordQuestVm>();
    }
}

public class WordQuestVm
{
    public long WordOptionId { get; set; }
    public string? WordOption { get; set; }
}
```

How to map WordVm to Word with the list using automapper.

I tried using the given code.

```
CreateMap<WordVm, Word>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.WordQuestList, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.WordQuestList));

        CreateMap<WordQuestVm, WordOption>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.WordOptionId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.WordOption));
```

facing issues in mapping the list...

Comment: *facing issues in mapping the list* Which issues?

Answer (score -1):

One possible way to map WordVm to Word with the list using automapper is to create a mapping from WordQuestVm to WordQuest, and then use that mapping in the mapping from WordVm to Word. For example:

```
CreateMap<WordQuestVm, WordQuest>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.WordOptionId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.WordOptionId))
.ForMember(dest => dest.WordOption, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<WordOption>(src)));

CreateMap<WordVm, Word>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name)) 
.ForMember(dest => dest.Definition, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Definition)) 
.ForMember(dest => dest.WordQuestList, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<List<WordQuest>>(src.WordQuestList)));
```

This way, you can map the nested list of WordQuestVm to the corresponding list of WordQuest in the Word entity. You can also use the ReverseMap method to create the reverse mapping from Word to WordVm if needed.

Comment: It's not clear which issues there are so how can you answer this? No doubt, one issue is mapping a string to an object (WordOption). You ignore that. Also, using `Mapper.Map` in a mapping configuration causes trouble when using `ProjectTo`.